# Add/delete members to M365 groups using MS Graph API with Golang

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to add and/or delete group members using graph/api with Golang

I am able to list members, or owners for groups, but not able to add to delete members.

```
//---CODE--- To list member of groups this code works an intended

cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential("7c...","16...","sj...", nil,)
auth, err := a.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"})
requestAdapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapter(auth)
graphClient := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)
result, err := graphClient.Users().Get()
// get member in 1 group
graphClientGroup := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(requestAdapter)
r2, err := graphClientGroup.GroupsById("...group-id...").Members().Get()
```

When I try any variation for adding including as listed in MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=go

```
requestBody := msgraphsdk.New()
requestBody.SetAdditionalData(map[string]interface{}{
"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
}
graphClient.GroupsById(&groupId).MembersById(&directoryObjectId).Post(requestBody)
```

This code will not compile, other variations will run but not produce new group members or return an error.

For deleting members in M365 groups I tried to run code without success such as:

```
graphClient.GroupsById("groupId...").MembersById("memberID...").Ref().Delete()
```

No errors are returned and NO member deleted from group?

Thank you, for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go#microsoft-graph-sdk-for-go):

The `Microsoft Graph Go SDK` is currently in Community Preview and breaking changes are expecting to happen to the SDK based on community's feedback.

The error with `post()` has been already reported. Details [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go/issues/155)

Comment: This issue is now fixed, as of 2022-05-31 v0.25.0

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed, as of 2022-05-31 v0.25.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).